# Git push error - failed to push some refs to <path>

Tags: bash, git, github, git-bash

I am trying to upload my code onto a repository I created on github but I get an error.
Assuming the URL of the repository is https://github.com/a, how do I go about uploading my code to my remote repository?

I tried the following commands on git bash after navigating INSIDE the folder I want to upload -

```
git init
(output - Reinitializing existing Git repository in C://(path)/.git/

git add.
(blank output)

git commit -m "Initial commit" 
(output- On branch main. nothing to commit, working tree clean)

git remote add origin https://github.com/(path).git
(output - error: remote origin already exists) 

git push origin master
(output - error:src refspec master does not match any
error failed to push some refs to https://github.com/(path).git)
```

Why is this happening and what could I do to push my code to my remote git repo? (I want to learn how to use git via cmd)

Thanks for reading my query!

Comment: you need to add an space between the `add` and the `.`(dot). That's must be the reason for you getting **nothing to commit** when you are commiting.

Comment: when you execute the first **push** into the local repository add the argument `-u`, this will set an "default" upstream for git pull/status/push.

Comment: Your `git init` output is telling you that you **already have a repository** and it is therefore not doing anything. Your `git remote add` output is telling you that the existing repository, which your `git init` did not change in any way, already has a remote named `origin` added. Your `git status` tells you that this repository seems otherwise fine: you're on your `main` branch and have some commits.

Comment: @MarcioRocha Won't Git prompt a "Command add. not found. Do you mean: add" or similar?

Answer (score 2):

note that you already have an remote repository configured as `origin` you must remove this configuration or rename then add the correctly repo.

the git command to remove remotes repositories by name is `git remote remove ${repo_name}`, in your case:

```
git remote remove origin
```

the git command to rename remotes repositories is:

```
git remote rename ${old_repo_name} ${new_repo_name}
```

then you can add an new remote with the name origin

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/(path).git
```

you can assume that the git command `git remote add origin https://github.com/(path).git` says to git configure an new remote repository into the current local repository, this remote config will "point" to the <URL> and the "alias" of this <URL> will be "origin" (or the name you specify between `add` and <URL>).

*in this case <URL>=https://github.com/(path).git*

With this you can have various remotes and specify then when you execute `git push ${repo_name}`

You can set an "default" upstream for git pull/status with `git push -u ${repo_name}`

Answer (score -1):

You wrote:

```
git commit -m "Initial commit" 
(output- On branch main. nothing to commit, working tree clean)

git push origin master
(output - error:src refspec master does not match any
```

Your init created a branch called *main* but you tried to push *master*, which doesn't exist. Try pushing main instead.